# American marrying Italian in Italy- Document Translation and Apostille questions

Tags: usa, immigration, marriage, italy, paperwork

I'm an American and I'm marrying an Italian citizen in Italy in the middle of September and also moving there.

We know that I need to get my birth certificate translated to Italian and have submitted it to be translated. My main question is, what do I need to get an Apostille stamp on? My birth certificate AND the translation?

I'm also unsure of where to get the Apostille stamp. Does it need to be done by the state that my birth certificate originally came from, or the state that I currently live?

Thanks for any help. 
Cheers.

Comment: The apostille comes from the state where the document was issued (because it attests to the validity of the issuing office). It can only be affixed to the original document, not to the translation.

Comment: To correct my last sentence, the translation probably has to be certified and notarized, and the notary's certification probably also needs an apostille. That apostille would be issued by the state where the notary is licensed, so not necessarily the same state as the other apostille. But the Italian authorities ought to have an explanation of all this; do they not?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like most goverments, the Italians don't give many absolute answers. They often defer to someone else, and then someone else. I've researched rather extensively online and haven't found much about the apostille. Your response is the most helpful thing I've found so far.  So in your theory, I should have my birth certificate translated here where I live and have it notorized, then send both off to my birth state to be apostille'd?  How do I get a notorization an apostille stamp?  Thanks again

Comment: You can get your birth certificate translated anywhere.  It's probably easiest to find a translator from the Italian consulate (consulates typically maintain a list of translators). This translator will be familiar with the authentication (apostille) process. You get the apostille from the Secretary of State. The BC apostille is issued by the state where the BC was issued, and the translation apostille is issued by the state where the notary or certified translator is certified. Therefore you won't get the translation apostille in your state of birth.

Comment: Also you may need to get a new copy of your BC first, because you typically can't get an apostille if the document is older than 6 months.  But that might vary from state to state; I've only gotten an apostille in New York State and that was 5 years ago.  The particulars of the process will be available from the certifying state.  For example: http://www.dos.ny.gov/licensing/apostille.html

Comment: After reviewing the page I linked to, I conclude that the 6-month requirement was imposed by the state where I was going to use the documents.  Italy might be more lenient.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this whole process, it is fairly simple. I would go to the Commune (ufficio) where you will be married, and ask your italian bride or husband to ASK THEM DIRECTLY what needs to be bollo'ed and stamped, and they should (hopefully) put an X on the documents that need a 16 or 32 or however much it costs now bollo (Mark).
Sincerely, and congrats,
Karl